# How can I align a button at the end of a sentence with TailwindCSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, styling

I am trying to align a button at the end of a line of text so it looks like the attached image [image: Goal]

Right now the button is next to the line of text at the correct height, but I can't get it any closer to the end of the sentence.
[image: currently looks like this]

```html
 <div className="flex flex-col lg:px-28 px-8 lg:mt-0 mt-8 w-[100%] ">
          <h2 className="font-bold text-4xl text-[#000000]">
            Hi, I&#39;m Shadi!
          </h2>
          <div className="flex">
            <p className="text-xl text-[#000000] leading-loose mr-2">
              I&#39;m a Web Developer from <br/>Washington, DC.
            </p>
            <Link
              className="mt-10 flex px-2 py-4 h-8 text-md rounded-lg 
              items-center justify-center whitespace-nowrap
              border-2 border-transparent
              bg-[#000000] text-[#F5F5F5] 
              dark:bg-[#f5f5f5] dark:text-[#000000]
              hover:opacity-60 hover:duration-300"
              onMouseEnter={() => setFocus(true)}
              onMouseLeave={() => setFocus(false)}
              target="_blank"
              href="/about"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              Learn More
              {learnMoreIcon}
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I want it to be scalable to stay shaped like a staircase at any size window (i.e. Top line of text is the shortest, bottom line is the longest).

Idk if its possible tbh but I don't see why not.

Comment: move the link into the paragraph. The button is shown on the right side because of the usage of Flexbox. The whole purpose of Flexbox is to move elements next to each other. Also, a paragraph by default is a block-level element and will not allow other elements to resume in the same line as it's content.

Comment: Convert your p tag into a simple div than put the link just after the text, it should be able to give you the desire result.